# Can't Hibernate or Suspend with Gnome or Unity

Tags: boot, gnome, suspend, hibernate, resume

When I try to suspend/hibernate my computer goes into suspend/hibernate mode but when I try to resume it boots all over again, although this does not happen using KDE. Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Hibernation is usually disabled by default. You should not see an option to do that.

Comment: Yeah I have activated it and I can hibernate my system either with terminal or the menu.....but when I turn on my system it boots afresh